# Google Translate API not as good as Google Translate Widget

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I have just started using the Google Translate API and the quality is nowhere as good as the Google Widget (found on translate.google.com).
For instance, the sentence **"It has potential but I need help setting it up"** is translated like so:

- **Google Widget:** "Il a du potentiel, mais j'ai besoin d'aide pour l'utiliser"
- **Translate API**: "Il a un potentiel mais je besoin d'aide à l'utiliser"

Anybody that can read french would tell you the translation given by the translate API is awful.

I am using V2 of the API so that's not the issue. Has anybody any clue on why this is happening? If we pay, should the translation be better or at least as good?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google translate API ability or inability to accurately translate French and is not programing related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google just released a version of his translation using Neural Networks that is already available on the translate.google.com but on the API, one has to apply as it is still in Beta and has a different pricing. 
Details at https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/premium